# Extract Year and Month Values from Column value and insert into MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have a file with four columns:

```
local_timestamp,    utc_timestamp,       pointname,      pointvalue
7/7/2017 12:29:00 PM,7/7/2017 6:59:00 AM,STS.PresentValue,1.0
7/7/2017 12:30:00 PM,7/7/2017 7:00:00 AM,STS.PresentValue,1.0
```

I have created a table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE  sample(
  `local_timestamp` DATETIME  NOT NULL,
  `utc_timestamp` DATETIME  NOT NULL,
  `pointname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `pointvalue` FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
  `year_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `month_id` INT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (year_id,month_id))
  PARTITION BY KEY() ;
```

Now since the file contains only 4 fields, but the table contains 6, how am i suppose to bulk insert the data  to table using LOAD DATA INFILE.

The `year_id` and `month_id` fields should have the year and month values from the `local_timestamp` field.

I am trying something as below, but its throwing an error.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/data/*'
INTO TABLE sample
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(@var1, @var2, pointname, pointvalue)
SET local_timestamp = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), utc_timestamp = STR_TO_DATE(@var2, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), year_id = YEAR(@var1),month_id = MONTH(@var1);

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'utc_timestamp = STR_TO_DATE(@utc_timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), pointname =' at line 6
```

Comment: update the rest of two fields with default or null or blank value and upload file

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal  have updated the question

Comment: I can use something else to transform and produce the desired data before inserting , but that would be an add on, but before i go and do something else I want to know if this can be possible via sql

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have got the working solution. back ticks made it work.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/data/file'
INTO TABLE sample
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(@var1, @var2, @pointname, @pointvalue)
SET `local_timestamp` = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), `utc_timestamp` = STR_TO_DATE(@var2, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), `pointname` = @pointname, `pointvalue` = @pointvalue, `year_id` = SUBSTRING(@var1,5,4) ,`month_id` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@var1,'/',1);
```